# How to set active only one link with react router for multiple url state?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, hybrid-mobile-app

I have three main links in my home page such as Lists, about and history. I want to get activate Lists link when i'm in details and photos screens. How to set active for that particular links?

Here is my router code,

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/">
        <IndexRedirect to="home/lists" />
        <Route path="home" component={Home}>
            <Route path="lists" component={Lists} />
            <Route path="details" component={Details} />
            <Route path="photos" component={Photos} />
            <Route path="about" component={About} />
            <Route path="history" component={History} />
        </Route> 
    </Route>
</Route>
```

Menu component,

```
<li><Link to="home/lists" activeClassName="active">Lists</Link></li>
<li><Link to="home/about" activeClassName="active">About</Link></li>
<li><Link to="home/history" activeClassName="active">History</Link></li>
```

I want to always active lists link when i'm in details and photos. How to get resolve this issue. I'm struggling past 3 hours to get fixed this issue. Someone please get me out from this issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use location object from router.

```
this.props.location.pathname
```

Stores information about your current URL. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
<Link to="home/lists" className={this.props.location.pathname === 'home/details' || (...) ? 'active' : 'notActive'}>Lists</Link>
```

Comment: @Mariusjasinski It is throwing error. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined".

Comment: This won’t work if your component is a pure function, since it will not have `location` passed through the props. In that case you should explicitly pass the `location` object to your function as a prop.